# Access Violationg when retrieving h_addr_list[0] C++

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, access-violation

I am trying to send a GET request and when I try to retrieve `h_addr_list[0]`, I get an access violation error trying to read at location  0x0000000C.

```
hostent* FAR hostname = gethostbyname(sDetails.host);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(LPDWORD)hostname->h_addr_list[0];
```

`sDetails.host` is set to http://www.google.ca for testing.

Comment: you should ever check if the result is not null

Comment: You aren't checking if `hostname` is actually a `NULL` pointer returned, which could happen probably.

Comment: OK, but why would it return a null pointer?

Comment: @swayz The [gethostbyname()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname) manpage explain the probable error conditions and behavior well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Winsock gethostbyname documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx):

> If no error occurs, **gethostbyname** returns a pointer to the **[hostent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738552.aspx)** structure described above. Otherwise, it returns a **null** pointer and a specific error number can be retrieved by calling **[WSAGetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580.aspx)**.

The documentation goes on to describe the expected error codes, and it includes example code for calling `gethostbyname` followed by `WSAGetLastError`.

Comment: Yes This worked, sorry for jumping the gun on this one everyone. :)